# WCF how to find Ip connected / connected client?

Tags: c#, wcf

Hello It should be on the side of the host WCF have to connect an event / client disconnects. Disabling occurs in this case after the session life time.

Every client I have to recognize (Ip address or specific information provided in the client settings is not important, the main thing to identify)). I use the re definition of the behavior of the endpoint.

```
class ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

        endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(new ClientTrackerChannelInitializer());
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```

> ClientTrackerChannelInitializer

```
  class ClientTrackerChannelInitializer : IChannelInitializer
    {

    internal static int ConnectedClientCount = 0;
public static ISubject<ClientConnectionInfo> ClientConnectChange { get; } = new Subject<ClientConnectionInfo>();


        public void Initialize(IClientChannel channel) //!!!!!!!I would like to see here about the Clint.
        {
            ConnectedClientCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} initialized", channel.SessionId);
            channel.Closed += ClientDisconnected;
            channel.Faulted += ClientDisconnected;

            ClientConnectChange.OnNext(new ClientConnectionInfo { Action = channel.State, SessionId = channel.SessionId, IpAdress = channel.LocalAddress.ToString()});
        }
        static void ClientDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var channel = (IClientChannel) sender;
            ConnectedClientCount--;
            ClientConnectChange.OnNext(new ClientConnectionInfo { Action = channel.State, SessionId = channel.SessionId, IpAdress = channel.LocalAddress.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

> Host Start

```
            string baseAddress = "http://192.168.1.33:4000/Service";
            service = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));

            //MEX EndPoint
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            service.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            service.AddServiceEndpoint( ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,   MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),"mex");

            //IContract EndPoint
            WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);      
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 25);  
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContract), binding, "");
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior());

            service.Open();
```

> Events Initialize and ClientDisconnected triggered properly. But no information about the client, I can learn from them not channel.RemoteAddress == null.

In advance thank you all !!

Comment: Have you tried checking `channel.RemoteAddress` during or after the `channel.Opening` event has fired?

Comment: I checked inside the Initialize method and ClientDisconnected. In both cases equal to NULL channel.RemoteAddress

Comment: I used: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]

Comment: inside the method initialize () State = Created.
inside the method Client Disconnected () State = Closed.
How do I catch Opened state?

Comment: I handle the event channel.Opened + = Channel Opened; and it is also equal to NULL channel.RemoteAddress

Comment: The problem is still relevant!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!